# DataDump - Answer posted before the question

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I *think* this isn't a duplicate...

I've been looking through the DataDump and I've noticed a number of posts (137) where the answer was posted *before* the question.

Now a difference of a few minutes I could understand as being down to time synchronisation issues between servers, however answer [#391523](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391523/) was apparently posted nearly 4 *days* before the question was asked! (Question posted Dec 24 '08 at 14:24, answer posted Dec 21 '08 at 23:29)

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions were merged; maybe the datestamp was for the later answer?

I know they were merged because I followed that topic very closely (and wrote the original compiled 'accepted' answer).

Comment: I remember that too. Ah, the memories... back then, theman was the only troll I'd ever seen on SO.

Comment: Ah, that would be it.  I didn't even realise it was possible to merge questions.

Comment: Well, to speak accurately: The answers were merged into one question. That may be What caused it.