# Answer posted 4 hours before question was asked?

Tags: bug, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back to the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future)

Yet again I assert my precognitive abilities, this time by answering [How does anyone remember the Dark One's name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4981/how-does-anyone-remember-the-dark-ones-name) 4 hours before it was asked.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Some people would be *happy* about accomplishments like this. All you Meta users do is complain complain complain.

Comment: @Cody: Did I accidentally add the [meta-tag:bug] tag? I meant to add the [meta-tag:brag] tag.

Comment: I'm assuming the cause is the same as [DataDump - Answer posted before the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38441/datadump-answer-posted-before-the-question)

Comment: @bemace: I think the answer on that question was that it was a merge bug. There doesn't appear to have been any merging going on with the above question.

Comment: The wombats are at it again? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future)

Comment: Same issue as before - clock drift on the web tier.

Comment: @Geoff 4 hours drift? Did someone forget to depress the Turbo button on one of your servers lately? :)