# Faster than the fastest FGITW ever (I answered a question before it was asked!)

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

Fear me. I've been able to [answer question before it was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312787/setting-the-ld-preload-environment-variable-for-commands-run-without-typing-the/10312860#10312860)!

:-)

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMben.png]

Comment: Refresh the page. You still have not broken the laws of physics.

Comment: Well, refreshing helps, but how could this happen? A bug, possibly. Anyway, the state I snapshoted might also be after refresh..

Comment: If you didn't refresh after answering, I can only assume that the javascript routines only updated the answer timestamp display and not the question.

Comment: @Oded, there are some javascript routines to update those times? I didn't know! But if yes, then they are not working correctly.

Comment: There are. The timestamp is static in the HTML, but some javascript converts them to the readable format, probably using the local time. You will see the number of minutes incrementing automatically on a page.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting that from, @Oded, but that would be news to me.

Comment: @balpha - Educated guess. If you don't refresh the page, the number of minutes next to `asked` or `answered` goes up as time goes by. I can only assume this is done via JS.

Comment: @Oded yep, that spooked me a few days back :O.

Comment: @Oded Apologies; Nick just told me that we've added timestamp updating recently. I hope that's not staying for long.

Comment: @balpha - Not if it is buggy. I don't really have a problem with the feature. Kinda like it really.

Comment: @balpha I think you guys have become slightly trigger-happy on the new shiny websockets feature ;-)

Comment: @balpha don't you have that big board at office with all the planned changes with big green V next to those what were done? ;)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd What's this "plan" thing? Also, I live 4000 miles away from the office :)

Comment: @balpha thought all developers work from office, while moderators are spread all over the world. Oh well.. :)

Comment: I'd be in favor of eliminating the "friendly" time. I'm a big boy and can figure out that 9:52 was an hour ago. While sorting helps, it is not always clear when there are edits or comments and everything within the last 31-89 minutes (or whatever the "1 hour ago" range is) imply that they all happened at the same time.

Comment: why was this closed? Is it a common practice to close bugreports you don't like as off topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Answer posted 4 hours before question was asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102059/answer-posted-4-hours-before-question-was-asked)

Comment: I once got an email and Outlook said it had been sent Tomorrow.

Comment: @gnostradamus, can't be duplicate of a bug that is [status-completed].

Comment: @Tomas: Code can always be re-broken. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Back to the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future)

Comment: MY EYES! AAH! Get font smoothing!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The date on the question wasn't updated while pulling in new answers via sockets - this will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Any chance something [went wrong again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137092)?

Comment: And [again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166205/date-shows-answered-before-the-question-is-asked)?