# Time auto refresh bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, live-refresh, time

How come this possible?:

[image]

What I did:

1. Visited question link.
2. Answered the question after read.
3. After some time refreshed page to see if any update.
4. Remain on screen.
5. The time for asking and answering question changes to above values.

---

Also I stayed for some more time and what I see is:

[image]

This times are also wrong. I answered a question a long ago not just 7 sec.

I guess there a small problem/bug in refreshing time. And as far as I can see edited time  do not get auto refreshed at all or may be I'm missing something. I'm using Google Chrome 19.0.1084.56 on Windows XP.

Comment: There is already tag for live refresh no need to create new one.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd sorry I didn't know that.

Comment: No problem. Anyway maybe [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130288/faster-than-the-fastest-fgitw-ever-i-answered-a-question-before-it-was-asked) has returned, or maybe you got network problem causing the AJAX requests to sometimes fail, the missing avatars in your screenshots are suspicious.

Comment: Missing avatars are due to images are blocked in my company. Not sure about the Ajax issue. I also can't see the image on the question that you suggest to be returned.

Comment: So good chance the company also block more stuff and it's affecting other things.. can you use some traffic monitor to see what's being blocked?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I also checked from an unblocked computer and I get same results. The time behavior is weird.

Comment: it's a bug in the time/space continuum

Answer (score 2):

The time is calculated based on the date and time from your local machine.  If your clock is off, so will the relative dates / times displayed on posts / comments.