# Time discrepancy on question page when your clock is "wrong"

Tags: bug, timezone, time

When I load a page, the times displayed are all right, regardless of how my clock is set up. But after about one minute, when the page is updated (via JavaScript, presumably) the times get messed up depending on how the clock were adjusted in computer settings:

[image]

When that happens, some actions in the page don't work right (for instance, I started writing a comment, when I tried to submit it nothing happened; I copied all text and reloaded the page, then pasted and submit, and it was fine). Only after I reload that page, and if I do it in the 1 minute window I have before it gets messed up again.

I tested setting up my clock as it was "supposed to be" (minus 1 hour: DST in my country was supposed to end yesterday, but didn't) and the times were right. As it is right now, the times show as "1 hour ago". If I set it to different values - say, 3 hours in the future - the discrepancy increases correspondingly (that "10 mins ago" shows as "4 hours ago"). I didn't test setting it to the past, out of fear of creating a time paradox... (or maybe I'm just lazy)

#### More details:

Where I live it's UTC-3 most of the year, UTC-2 when DST is active. I'm running Windows XP. The computer (incorrectly) disabled DST, so I had to manually adjust it. If I do it by:

- keeping my timezone as UTC-3, but adjusting the clock (subtracting 1 hour), the bug happens;
- changing the timezone to UTC-2, keeping the clock as it is, the bug **does not** happen.

In other words, for my particular case I've already found a way to avoid the bug, but in case you're not aware of it I'm reporting it...

Comment: Umm, I don't know about you, but any time I manually set the time to something other than the *actual* time it is for that timezone, I would kind of expect things not to work correctly. If your annoyance is with DST turning off incorrectly, that's not really SE's bug to deal with.

Comment: @animuson It should at least let you submit a comment

Comment: @Asad: That one seems a little odd, but I imagine it's something with the time checker becoming *extremely* confused when trying to check the rate limiting for a futuristic time.

Comment: @animuson "If your annoyance is with DST turning off incorrectly" Nope, as I said in the last sentence I've already learned how to correctly set the time in my system (and hopefully everyone should be setting their clocks to the correct time). The reason I'm reporting is just to raise awareness that contents returned via "normal" HTML are discrepant to contents updated via JavaScript, and that some things in the site - not just comments, but also votes, and maybe editing - don't work while in this state. Whether this is important enough to be fixed or not, that's up to the devs...

Comment: (BTW, I'm confident that the server is smart enough not to rely on client data to do important things like rate limiting things - but that doesn't change the fact that the UI becomes unresponsive)

Comment: NVM that, found a similar question ([Time auto refresh bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137092/time-auto-refresh-bug)), closed as "by design".