# Comment editing relies on device's clock to lock editing

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, comment-edits

Editing comments through the Android app relies on the device's local clock to determine whether it's still available for editing.

If my device's clock is manually adjusted to be ahead of the local time, the server is assuming for me, it shows new comments as posted "`delta-t` minutes ago".

Eg. `delta-t` could be: "(UTC+2 + 13min) - (UTC+2)" for "13 minutes ago".

I can't seem to see what exactly changes when my clock is behind.

Comment: Simply don't mess with your local clock. No bug here as far as I can tell, and I'm pretty sure you can't really edit the comment after the 5 minutes window, as there is server side check when submitting. (i.e. it's only a display "bug")

Comment: Which is *still* a bug :/  Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7877707/)

Comment: Repro'd on v1.0.83, and interestingly, setting the clock behind make you able to "edit" the comment again (though, the server will still prevent it because of 5-minutes rule). Also, possibility of a bigger issue related to *all* timestamps.

Comment: Just curious, you consider [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8yI95.png) a bug too? /cc @Andrew - because it's exactly the same.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think it's the same, since it's a possible genuine issue with [Android time synchronization](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/clock-off-by-4-min-even-if-use-network-value-is-on-probably-due-to-an-app). But then, I just found that [it's status by-design to use local clock on browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146663/241919).

Comment: @Andrew still, as long as there is no permanent effect anywhere, it can't really be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. Even if you try to fiddle with your time settings so it thinks you are in the edit time window, the server will reject an edit based on the checks there.

If you are messing around, it is your problem. There is nothing for the SO development team to do.

Comment: Ah, wait wait wait. It only doesn't work because, relying on my "+some_time" device clock, it thinks every post is "some_time" later than it actually is. That is, there is no edit option even within the edit window. Because there is no edit time window.

Comment: I think it just remembers your comment time on your device. If you change your time then it isn't the apps fault.

Comment: Maybe I just don't quite understand you. Can you tell the exact steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I understand what the OP means: you can try it on the app by commenting a post, then changing the time to 10 minutes later, and try to edit the same comment again (after refreshing the question); the timestamp will be added by 10 minutes, hiding the "edit" icon. Meanwhile, by setting the time sooner than current time (e.g. 2007), you can show the "edit" icon on any comment; the timestamp will show "just now".

Comment: So is that a bug? The client side check uses the clock time, the server double checks it and will reject the edit. @andrew

Comment: @Andrew I agree with Patrick here, that's not a bug. It's the same as messing with the DOM in a browser, trying to do things you can't do, e.g. upvote own post. Been there tried that, it's all locked away behind solid server validation.

Comment: I don't think the bug is about "server rejecting the edit" (it's by-design, and I don't have a problem with that). However, SE API returns the timestamp in UNIX time, and the device (client) convert it to readable timestamp using its local clock. I think it can be made device-independent by getting current UNIX time and use that as the time reference instead. I can see it as a real issue, given that [it's possible to have wrong time even with network sync](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/clock-off-by-4-min-even-if-use-network-value-is-on-probably-due-to-an-app)

Comment: Forget my comment above, [it's status by-design on PC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146663/241919) too.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

When you create a comment **in the app**, the app will keep track of the local time of the server's response as the official start of the 5 minute counter.  If the app crashes or leaves memory, or the comment was created on the web, the app won't have information to calculate the true edit window and will instead use the comment's creation date property as it currently does.  All bets are off if you edit the time after posting the comment.

Times will still be shown with an offset.  That's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for all the reasons in the comments and answers.

[Relevant.](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)