# Date shows answered before the question is asked

Tags: support, timestamps

I believe this is a bug, I managed to answer this question before it was asked.

[Passing variable to.exe in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692598/passing-variable-to-exe-in-sql/14692630#14692630)

I know this bug has been reported before (and thus might be considered a duplicate) but that question was marked as completed.  I've heard when the same bug is seen then a new question should be created.

[image: example]

Comment: As an aside, just in case you don't know but do care: [PNG vs JPEG](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/).

Comment: SO also showed me an error page when I saved this question but it seems to have shown up...?

Comment: @Arjan - I can't actually see the images on SO because of work firewall -- is it so bad I should redo it?

Comment: Nope, not bad enough :-) (But surely shows compression artifacts.)

Comment: @Arjan - *sigh* - this is the result of spacing out during a save as...

Comment: Just to be sure, @Hogan, my comment was only --sightly-- relevant if you didn't know about it to start with! No worries. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your post was inserted using AJAX, but the rest of the page was not.

The relative time you see on the question is from when you first loaded the page instead. It is supposed to adjust automatically using JS but by the looks of it that stalled for you.
Reload the page and both relative timestamps are perfectly normal.

When in doubt, hover over the relative time to see the absolute time instead:

[image: absolute time]

The question was asked at 17:58:49, you answered at 18:00:38. No time machines were necessary.

Comment: ...but *that* relative time updates automatically as well? I guess the local clock must be off by some minutes then as well?

Comment: This is very strange -- before I took the screenshot I checked the hover and they showed the same -- maybe this is only fixed on a refresh?

Comment: What did they show? The same time? It could be your local clock is off and for some elements your PC time is used instead of server time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Sadly I don't remember, I just checked to see the time stamps were wrong relativity, that is, mine was prior to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Relative times are calculated client side.  Check your clock to see if you're synced up with the nearest NTP server.

Comment: ...but then wouldn't *both* times be off with the same difference...? (Just curious...)

Comment: @Arjan There can be a mismatch when one timestamp has been updated client-side and the other was new content pulled from the server (via WebSockets).

Comment: I don't know if it is syncing with an NTP server but Lotus is syncing the time every time I check for email (every 15 mins).